# I am not able to replace content from a file using shell script

Tags: shell, replace, scripting

(function(){})();
window.getJetPaths=function(b){var c={knockout:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/knockout/knockout-3.4.0","knockout.mapping":"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/knockout/knockout.mapping-latest",jquery:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/jquery/jquery.min",jqueryui:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom.min","jqueryui-amd":"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.12.0.min",promise:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/es6-promise/es6-promise.min",
require:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/require/require",hammerjs:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/hammer/hammer-2.0.8.min",ojs:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/oj/v4.2.0/min",ojL10n:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/oj/v4.2.0/ojL10n",ojtranslations:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/oj/v4.2.0/resources",ojdnd:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/dnd-polyfill/dnd-polyfill-1.0.0.min",
signals:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/js-signals/signals.min",customElements:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/webcomponents/custom-elements.min",crossroads:null,history:null,text:"/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239.001032001/js/oraclejet/js/libs/require/text"},a;for(a in c)c[a]?b[a]=c[a]:delete b[a];return b};
window.getJetBundles=function(){return window.isDevMode?[]:"customElements hammerjs jqueryui jqueryui-amd jqueryui-amd/data jqueryui-amd/disable-selection jqueryui-amd/focusable jqueryui-amd/ie jqueryui-amd/keycode jqueryui-amd/plugin jqueryui-amd/position jqueryui-amd/safe-active-element jqueryui-amd/safe-blur jqueryui-amd/scroll-parent jqueryui-amd/tabbable jqueryui-amd/unique-id jqueryui-amd/version jqueryui-amd/widget jqueryui-amd/widgets/draggable jqueryui-amd/widgets/mouse jqueryui-amd/widgets/sortable knockout knockout.mapping ojL10n ojdnd ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtAxis ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtChart ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtDiagram ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtGauge ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtLegend ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtNBox ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtOverview ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtPanZoomCanvas ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtPictoChart ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtSubcomponent ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtTagCloud ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtThematicMap ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtTimeAxis ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtTimeComponent ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtTimeline ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtToolkit ojs/internal-deps/dvt/DvtTreeView ojs/ojaccordion ojs/ojanimation ojs/ojarraydatagriddatasource ojs/ojarraypagingdatasource ojs/ojarraytabledatasource ojs/ojbutton ojs/ojchart ojs/ojcheckboxset ojs/ojcollapsible ojs/ojcollectiondatagriddatasource ojs/ojcollectionpagingdatasource ojs/ojcollectiontabledatasource ojs/ojcollectiontreedatasource ojs/ojcomponentcore ojs/ojcomponents ojs/ojconveyorbelt ojs/ojcore ojs/ojcube ojs/ojcustomelement ojs/ojdatacollection-common ojs/ojdatacollection-utils ojs/ojdatagrid ojs/ojdatagrid-model ojs/ojdataprovider ojs/ojdataprovideradapter ojs/ojdatasource-common ojs/ojdatetimepicker ojs/ojdefer ojs/ojdiagram ojs/ojdialog ojs/ojdomscroller ojs/ojdvt-base ojs/ojeditablevalue ojs/ojeventtarget ojs/ojfilmstrip ojs/ojflattenedtreedatagriddatasource ojs/ojflattenedtreetabledatasource ojs/ojgauge ojs/ojindexer ojs/ojinputnumber ojs/ojinputtext ojs/ojjquery-hammer ojs/ojjsontreedatasource ojs/ojkeyset ojs/ojknockout ojs/ojknockout-model ojs/ojknockout-validation ojs/ojkoshared ojs/ojlabel ojs/ojlegend ojs/ojlistdataproviderview ojs/ojlistview ojs/ojmasonrylayout ojs/ojmenu ojs/ojmessaging ojs/ojmodel ojs/ojmodule ojs/ojmoduleanimations ojs/ojnavigationlist ojs/ojnbox ojs/ojoffcanvas ojs/ojoptgroup ojs/ojoption ojs/ojpagingcontrol ojs/ojpagingcontrol-model ojs/ojpagingdatagriddatasource ojs/ojpagingtabledatasource ojs/ojpictochart ojs/ojpopup ojs/ojpopupcore ojs/ojprogress ojs/ojprogressbar ojs/ojpulltorefresh ojs/ojradiocheckbox ojs/ojradioset ojs/ojrouter ojs/ojrowexpander ojs/ojselectcombobox ojs/ojslider ojs/ojsunburst ojs/ojswipetoreveal ojs/ojswitch ojs/ojtable ojs/ojtable-model ojs/ojtabs ojs/ojtagcloud ojs/ojtemplateengine ojs/ojthematicmap ojs/ojtime-base ojs/ojtimeline ojs/ojtoolbar ojs/ojtouchproxy ojs/ojtrain ojs/ojtree ojs/ojtree-model ojs/ojtreemap ojs/ojvalidation ojs/ojvalidation-base ojs/ojvalidation-datetime ojs/ojvalidation-number ojtranslations/nls/localeElements ojtranslations/nls/ojtranslations promise signals text".split(" ")};
window.getUifwkBundles=function(){return window.isDevMode?[]:"uifwk/js/util/ajax-util uifwk/js/util/df-util uifwk/js/util/logging-util uifwk/js/sdk/logging-feature-usage-util uifwk/js/util/message-util uifwk/js/util/mobile-util uifwk/js/util/preference-util uifwk/js/util/screenshot-util uifwk/js/util/typeahead-search uifwk/js/util/usertenant-util uifwk/js/util/zdt-util uifwk/js/util/uifwk-preload-util uifwk/js/sdk/context-util uifwk/js/sdk/menu-util uifwk/js/widgets/aboutbox/js/aboutbox uifwk/js/widgets/brandingbar/js/brandingbar uifwk/js/widgets/datetime-picker/js/datetime-picker uifwk/js/widgets/navlinks/js/navigation-links uifwk/js/widgets/timeFilter/js/timeFilter uifwk/js/widgets/widgetselector/js/widget-selector uifwk/js/widgets/tooltip/tooltip uifwk/js/sdk/widget-selector-util text!uifwk/js/widgets/aboutbox/html/aboutbox.html text!uifwk/js/widgets/navlinks/html/navigation-links.html text!uifwk/js/widgets/brandingbar/html/brandingbar.html text!uifwk/js/widgets/timeFilter/html/timeFilter.html text!uifwk/js/widgets/datetime-picker/html/datetime-picker.html text!uifwk/js/widgets/widgetselector/html/widget-selector.html".split(" ")};
//# sourceMappingURL=jetLoader.map

This is the file content here i want to replace **window.getJetPaths** whole defenition with a return statement only.
It is giving errors for not able to replace "/,{,}"

```
Below is my script:

#!/bin/bash
filePath='D:/emsaasui/uifwk/libs/4.2.0-41239/js/jetLoader.js'

line=$(awk '/getJetPaths/{print NR}' $filePath)
str=$(tail -n +$line $filePath)
#echo $str
tempStr=""
count=0
for (( i=0 ; i < ${#str} ; i++ )) {
    arr[$i]=${str:i:1}
    #printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
        if [[ ${arr[$i]} = '{' ]]
        then
        count=$((count+1))
        echo $count
    fi
        if [[ $count -eq "1" || $count -eq "2" ]]
        then
        tempStr=${tempStr}${arr[$i]}

        fi
        if [[ ${arr[$i]} = '}' ]]
        then
        count=$((count-1))
       if [[ $count = 0 ]]
        then
        break
        fi
   fi
   }
   echo $tempStr
sed 's/\\$tempStr{\([^}]*\)}/\1 %/g'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not reading that. I know people intentionally leave out js formatting to save a few bytes - format it anyway if you want help. That's horrible, and way too long to ask anyone to wade through like that. Also, [please read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) the question guidelines, [including mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and maybe show us some example output? Did you get an error message?  Did you try simpler subsets of the data? http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: Thats the as it is content of the file

Answer (score 1):

Simplest case - it's all on one line anyway. Just do a literal substitution.
Assuming file is named x -

```
sed 's/window.getJetPaths=function.*return b};/window.getJetPaths=function(b){return b};/' x > y
```

Watch the metacharacters. Sed gives special meaning to those, and they don't match unless carefully qualified, or included in a broad match.

Comment: And yes, I read it after all. I'm a sucker for a problem I can fix, lol

Comment: Hey Paul, not able to replace with that, its not in one line thats the problem.

Comment: Even if the content is in one line still its not working, nothing is getting replaced

Comment: Metacharacter pollution. Try the simplified match pattern.